# Set <p:editor value> to List or ArrayList, can we drag object from another table to editor?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, editor

Can we set value of `<p:editor>` not a String, for example List of objects.

```
private List<Users> objectList;
// or
private List<String> objectList;
```

```html
<p:editor value="#{viewBean.objectList}" />
```

I want to move list of objects to editor, is it possible?

Comment: I would suggest concatenating all the `String`s from the `List<String>` into a single `String` field, provide it for user edition, then when submitting this field, convert the `String` back into `List<String>` by using `String#split` or similar.

Comment: Yes thanks, I am thinking about, but will be nice move/or drag object, first time what I need list with editor:)

Comment: Based on your comment, I think you should provide your functional requirement along with your proposed solution, we may be able to provide other alternatives for that case.

Answer (score 0):

I just used StingBuffer and in every add, just append the string values..